# Django rest framework api

Tags: python, django, rest, django-views, django-rest-framework

I want to add to my Django project (using Django rest framework ) new get function.
I want it to just send to me in Json "Hello world" without writing or without opening a table in the DB
this is my code:

```
@api_view()
def about(request):
    return Response({"message": "Hello, world!"})
```

i put it in view.py
what more i should do the make it work?
when i run the server and write this lines

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/about
```

i want it to saw me "`{"message": "Hello, world!"}`"

Comment: And what you've got instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your 'urls.py':

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ...
    url(r'^about/$', views.about),
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks! if i want to send parameters to my function how i can do it?

Comment: Tutorials and docs are your friends.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/intro/tutorial03/

Answer (score 1):

I think you should register url path to `urls.py` first. And then update settings.py.

Here are some instructions for you about Django rest framework quickstart.
http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/quickstart/

Comment: yeah i thought so but i didn't know how

Answer (score -2):

To send parameters you can added them in the URL and ask for request.GET inside your function, even you can make a POST and ask for request.data inside your function.

your url: /about/?start_date=2016/08/20&end_date=2016/08/21

```
def about(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    """"
    Is called by a GET method.
    ISO format: YYYY/MM/DD and in UTC.
    """

    start_date_str = request.GET.get("start_date")
    end_date_str = request.GET.get("end_date")

    return Response({"message": "Hello, world!"})
```

Another way:

Your url: /about/100/

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
...
url(r'^about/(?P<object_pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.example),
...

def example(self, request, object_pk, *args, **kwargs):
    """"
    Is called by a GET method.
    """
    # do something with your object

    return Response({"message": "Hello, world!"})
```

Comment: This answer is not clear at all, please specify more details regarding what you are trying to say.